# Method Overloading not working as expected

Tags: java, methods, floating-point, overloading, long-integer

I am new to Java and trying to learn Method Overloading and got bit confused. Here is my program

```
class Adder {
    static void add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("a method invoked");
    }

    static void add(long a, int b) {
        System.out.println("b method invoked");
    }
}
class TestMethodOverloading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Adder.add( 9223372036854775807,12);
    }
}
```

I am getting compiler error saying

```
java: integer number too large
```

I am confused why method add with parameter long is not called here?

Comment: It is not a problem with overloading, but how you create `long` literal. Without `L` suffix your number represents `int` but that number is out of `int` range.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the L at the end of the number to denote it's a long.